# Duda sobre click en submit php jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Yo intentando aprender un poco mas, hace unos meses a modo de aprendizaje desarrollé un carrito de compras muy básico, todo en **PHP**. Por limitaciones varias cada vez que cambio de pantalla vuelvo a recargar algunas secciones que no varían como ser encabezados y pie, lo cual me parece que no es la  forma. Investigando JQuery encontré la funcion **load** y **POST**, pero no me funcionaron como imaginaba.

1. Estoy en una pagina llamada **detalle.php**, aqui visualizo 1 artículo que preseleccioné y puedo ver sus características antes de cargarlo al carrito. El **form** es el siguiente :

```html
<div id="detalle_titulo">
  <h3><?php echo $nombre?></h3>
</div>
<div id="detalle_foto">
  <img src="<?php echo $imagen?>" width="180px" height="180px">
</div>
<div id="detalle_precio">
  <p><strong>Precio :</strong> $
    <?php echo $precio?>
  </p>
</div>
<div id="detalle_stock">
  <p><strong>Stock :</strong>
    <?php echo $stock?>
  </p>
</div>
<div id="detalle_desc">
  <p><strong>Descripción :</strong>
    <?php echo $desc?>
  </p>
</div>
<form action="carrito.php" method="post" name="compra">
  <input name="id_txt" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id?>" />
  <input name="nombre" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $nombre?>" />
  <input name="precio" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $precio?>" />
  <input name="cantidad" type="hidden" value="1" />
  <input name="stock" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $stock?>" />
  <?php if ($stock>0) { ?>
  <div id="detalle_caja_botones">
    <input class="boton_detalle" name="cancelar" type="submit" value="Cancelar" />
    <input class="boton_detalle" id="bbb" name="Comprar" type="submit" value="Comprar" />
  </div>
  <?php }else{ echo "Producto temporalmente agotado"; ?>
  <input class="boton_detalle" name="Cancelar" type="submit" value="Cancelar" />
  <?php } ?>
```

Cuando le doy click al botón que a modo de prueba le puse **id="bbb"** llamo a **carrito.php** y le paso por **POST** 5 valores, que luego tomo en **carrito.php** para agregarlos y mostrar una tabla con el pedido actualizado. De este modo, estoy recargando la web completa con todas sus secciones lo cual me gustaría evitar, ya que solo necesito mostrar una tabla y que todo lo demas quede como está. Para no perder el hilo, refresco que estoy en **detalle.php** y llamo a carrito.php pasandole 5 valores por **POST**. Quise probar cargando **carrito.php** como un HTML externo; En la cabecera de **detalle.php** agregué la libreria JQuery y lo siguiente:

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#bbb').click(function(evento) {
      //evento.preventDefault();
      $(".productos").load('carrito.php');
    });
  }); 
< /script>
```

===================================================
**.productos** es el **div** donde quiero mostrar la tabla, primero me ocurrió que me recargaba **carrito.php** completa, luego probé con **evento.preventDefault();** pero el problema es que no envía los 5 valores por **POST**.

¿Alguna sugerencia de como lograr lo que necesito? 
Gracias adelantadas !!!

Answer (score 2):

Lo que necesitas es enviar la información vía post pero a través de un ajax, el cual se encargará de cargar solo la capa (div) que tiene la data del carrito, ejemplo:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#bbb').click(function() {
        var action = $('#compra').attr('action'); 
        var datos = $('#compra').serialize();
        $.ajax({ 
            url: action,
            type:'post',
            data: datos,
            beforeSend: function(){ 
                $('#div').html('Cargando'); 
            },
            success: function(response){ 
                $('#div').html(response); 
            }
        }); 
    });
});
```

Recuerda a tu form usar id="compra"

Espero te sirva

Sldos

Comment: Recuerda añadir el `evento.preventDefault();` sino el formulario irá a la página donde el `action` esté apuntando

Answer (score 1):

Le estás pegando a alguna base de datos? Si es así tendrías que mandar un post a la url. Después por get tenes la info. Con él load cargarías de forma dinámica también pero haciendo referencia a un file

Comment: Muchas gracias ! Me sirvió !